# Creating Application using AIDE and Exporting to Eclipse Cause some part of the APP to go missing

Tags: android, eclipse

I created an APP using AIDE for android and copied the folder to Eclipse and exported to APK with the certificate. But when i complied in AIDE, the menu showed up but after exporting from Eclipse the same APP has the menu option missing from it.

Any idea why?

P.s. I am trying to submit my app but the APK from the AIDE has Android Team certificate which doesnt allow me to upload to publish, so I am stuck... Please help!

Thanks

Comment: AIDE is relatively new, and it's possible you have found a defect..

Comment: IF I somehow can send you the Project, would you be kind enough to take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: no, sorry.  I don't really have time.  Just make the sure the code is identical on both AIDE and in eclipse.  Or, try connecting your phone to your computer and manually copying over the files into a new android project in eclipse.

Comment: i copied the entire folder from the phone to my pc but u think i should import directly from the phone?
on my phone when the user clicks MENU, it comes up but after compiling from the PC, theres no MENU.